# How to read in a file and sort that file into different types of data all into specific arrays stored in a struct

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I need to be able to read in (first number is meant to be id number followed by transactions, making bank statement code, d means deposit, w is withdrawal, numbers after are amount):

```
123     d45.10  d50.45  d198.56 w45.67
345     w34.00  d4.56   w45.13  d23.23  w23.12
639     d1000.34    d1234.56    w34.33  w345.87 w22.13
890     d345.67 d123.67 d45.99  d45.99  w34.77
666     d66.60  d666.66 d6.66   d66.6   d6666.66
```

and have it sort into different arrays all stored within a struct. I have tried string stream and various other things i thought of, I'm like medium versed in c++, in the first year class to be specific.

This is the code I have so far, The first set of read ins is working properly but I cannot get the second one to work:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;

struct PersonAcct {
    int acct_num[5];
    string name[5];
    double acct_bal[5];
};

struct PersonTrans {
    int acct_num[5];
    double trans[20];
    char d_p[20];
};

int main() {
    ifstream ifacc("accounts.txt");
    PersonAcct p;

    if (ifacc.is_open()) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
            ifacc >> p.acct_num[i];
            ifacc >> p.name[i];
            ifacc >> p.acct_bal[i];
        }
    }
    ifacc.close();

    ifstream iftrans;
    iftrans.open("transactions.txt");
    PersonTrans q;

    string line,line2,line3,line4,line5;
    if (iftrans.is_open()) {
        int counter = 0;
        while (getline(iftrans,line)) {
            cout << line << endl;
            counter++;
        }       
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated! As I said before I am pretty new in retrospect to most of you on here so please be detailed or explain it for someone a bit daft in this subject, as I prob could be considered. I thank you and wish you a happy early holiday season!

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried putting your line into a stringstream?

Comment: Regarding `for (size_t i = 0; i <= 4; i++)`, I believe they want you to use a `std::vector` and something like `while (...)`. Also see [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/608639).

Comment: The problem is, how you get rid of those characters before the numbers, right? Do they hold any meaing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correct, you need to parse different words in different lines. You should be able to get this done easily with `std::stringstream`.

e.g.

```
...
iftrans.open("transactions.txt");
if (iftrans.is_open())
{
    int counter = 0;
    string line;
    while (getline(iftrans, line))  // iterate through lines
    {
        int id;
        string word;
        stringstream ss(line);
        ss >> id;             // first word is the ID
        while (ss >> word)    // iterate though words of current line
        {
            switch (word[0])  // a word starts with either `w` or `d`
            {
                case 'w':
                {
                    // remaining characters represent a valid double
                    double const val = stod(word.substr(1));
                    // process withdrawal 
                    // ...
                    break;
                }
                case 'd':
                {
                    double const val = stod(word.substr(1));
                    // process deposit
                    // ...
                    break;
                }
                default: break;  // error?
            }
        }
        counter++;
    }
}
```

You may need to do additional error handling if the commented assumptions are not guaranteed to be valid always.

Answer (score 1):

So I probably implemented it stupidly but here's what I thought you should do. Since the first thing will always be an ID I added that to acct_num;

Next I have a while loop for the line, I create a new string stream (Probably bad form, unsure) using a substring of everything after the first letter. Then I check the first letter of each transaction whether or not its a d or a w and put them into arrays. I had two counters for the w and d arrays. If they were vectors this wouldn't be necessary.

I wasn't sure what your original struct meant so I just created an array for deposits and withdrawals.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;

struct PersonTrans {
    int acct_num[5];
    double deposits[20];
    double withdrawals[20];
};

int main() {
    ifstream iftrans;
    iftrans.open("transactions.txt");
    PersonTrans q;


    if (iftrans.is_open()) {
      int i = 0;
      int d = 0;
      int w = 0;
      string line;

      while (getline(iftrans,line)) {
        stringstream in(line);
        string tmp;
        int idNumber;
        in >> idNumber;
        q.acct_num[i] = idNumber;

        while(in >> tmp)   {
          double value;
          std::stringstream transaction(tmp.substr(1)); 
          transaction >> value;
          if (tmp[0] == 'd'){
            q.deposits[d] = value;
            d++;
          }
          else if (tmp[0] == 'w'){
            q.withdrawals[w] = value;
            w++;
          }
        }

        i++; 

      }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
      cout << q.deposits[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The only question I have is that the withdrawals and the deposits are not being separate properly I will play around with it but got any tips on that I see you implemented a sorting system but it seems to be over looked by the compiler.

Comment: I added another for loop to print out the withdrawals array and it all seems to be correct on my end. Could you update the main post with what's happening?